# I'm not sure what to do with my code. fraction conversions

Tags: java, fractions

I'm not sure what to add to `//Sample 3`, can anyone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm writing to write the final part where else if the improper fraction converts to a whole integer, but i don't know how to write that

```
package ch2_project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch2_project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a numerator: ");
        int numerator = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a denominator: ");
        int denominator = input.nextInt();

        if (numerator < denominator)
        {  
            System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " is a proper     fraction"); // Sample 2
        }
        else
        {
            int mix = numerator / denominator;
            int remainder = numerator % denominator;    
            System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " is a improper fraction and it's mixed fraction is " + mix + " and " remainder + " / " + denominator);// Sample 1
        }
        else if ()
        {
            int whole = numerator / denominator 
            System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " is an improper fraction and it can be reduced to " + whole);//Sample 3      
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you do something wrong? What makes you think so. Please explain. Meaning, tell us what your problem is.

Comment: @imustbejulia :  aside from the problem you're trying to solve, the ordering of your else and else if clauses are backwards and need to be swapped around.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an addition operator before remainder causing the compiler to throw an error about an unexpected symbol. Your concatenation isn't working due to the error here:

```
System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " is a improper fraction and it's mixed fraction is " + mix + " and " remainder + " / " + denominator);// Sample 1
                                                                                                                          ^
```

It should be changed to:

```
System.out.println(numerator + " / " + denominator + " is a improper fraction and it's mixed fraction is " + mix + " and " + remainder + " / " + denominator);// Sample 1
```

Notice the added `+` to remedy the problem, which was a missing symbol causing concatenation to fail.

Working example: [Here](http://ideone.com/E5fD9G)

## Edit

Seeing that you've edited the code, the `else` and `else if` statements are backwards. Also, the `else if` has no condition. To detect if fractions can be simplified to a whole number, do this:

```
else if(numerator%denominator == 0)
```

This will evaluate if `numerator` is divisible by `denominator`, yielding a whole number.

Comment: wouldn't he need to use double also if he want to show decimals?

Comment: @FarazDurrani But he doesn't want to show decimals. He want to say `7/3 = 2 and 1/3`

Comment: Nope. This is a fraction converter. What it does is it uses the trunctation of integer types to its advantage

Comment: oh sorry didnt read the question properly @Andreas and AndrewL